# Set Input Text Type Width It's Value Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bDaGV/1/

Is there anyway to set the width of an input text type to be the width of the value inside?

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
  width:auto;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('input[type=text]').css('width', $(this).val());
```

Comment: Are you wanting the input box to expand if the characters inside end up taking up more space than the input?

Comment: No the size of each input should be the elements value.

Comment: Yes, but do you want the size to change when you type in the input, thus changing the value ?

Comment: Oh, I'm with you. One second.

Comment: Yes (I have to wait 9 minutes before I can accept the answer)

Comment: Well, do you want me to write a quick fiddle to expand it as you type...?

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a css only solution, but all the research I was doing before evidently that's not possible with this type of element. It'd work of I used contenteditable, on a separate element, but this works fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the size trick

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('size', function() {
    return this.value.length;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDaGV/2/)

For completeness, to make it "auto expand", you'd need an event handler as well

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).attr('size', this.value.length);
}).trigger('keyup');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDaGV/3/)

Comment: Darnit, beat me to it :-P I was typing up the same fiddle hahaha. Upvoted.

Comment: don't forget to recommend a monospace font or else "..." will look funny.

Comment: I was trying css I didn't think about the size handler. Thanks!

Comment: *sigh*, yet again beat me to it haha. Well done @adeneo.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack a span with the contenteditable attribute then style it to look like an input:

```
<span class="input" contenteditable id="input1">ddd</span>
<style>
  span.input {
    border: thin black solid;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
</style>
```

Given jQuery, it's easy to get that text with something like $('#input1').text();

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeAndrieu/qYpAK/1/